# Custom block is not showing on my account page

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

I created a block on `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mostviewed.php`

Mostviewed.php

```
<?php

class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addViewsCount();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}
```

On my `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml` included my block as below

`<block type="customer/account_dashboard" name="customer_account_dashboard" template="customer/account/dashboard.phtml">
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                <block type="catalog/product_mostviewed" name="catalog_product_mostviewed" as="most_viewed" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml"/>
            </block>`

I added below in my `dashboard.phtml`

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('most_viewed') ?>`

I added template file in `MY_THEME/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml` But it is not showing and no error tagged in `system.log` also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not need to add code at customer.xml at base package.

Just create `local.xml` at `app/design/frontend/YOUR_Package/Your_Theme/layout` ***if localxml does not exit.***

and put `mostviewed.phtml` file at  `app/design/frontend/YOUR_Package/Your_Theme/template/atalog/product/`

Using reference tag `<reference name="ReferenceBlockName" >` you can add  `..catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml`.

**local.xml look like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
..
<!-- add the most view -->
<customer_account_index>
<reference name="customer_account_dashboard">
<block type="catalog/product_mostviewed" name="catalog_product_mostviewed" as="most_viewed" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml"/>
</reference>
</customer_account_index>
.....
</layout>
```

then called child block  at  dashboard.phtml by

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('most_viewed') ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> On my app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml included my
>   block as below

if your theme has same file it will load from your theme and not from base theme so add this in your theme layout

> I added template file in MY_THEME/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml

make sure you have added in `MY_THEME/template/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml`

Comment: Yes, I added in `MY_THEME/template/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml` only

Comment: @anto.nishanth updated my answer

Comment: @anto.nishanth you can accept and up vote

Comment: @raj don't hijack..........